# ldapsearch filter memberOf group returning no results

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have ran into problem using `memberOf` filter in my ldapsearch query. The customer is using `OpenLDAP.

I have a group of users with 3 members

[image: Members of User Group X]

When I query for users using ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p 393 -x -z 3 -b "o=XY,dc=group,dc=com,dc=xyz,dc=cz" "(&(objectClass=person))" 1.1
```

I get results containing also user `XYZ`.

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <o=XYZ,dc=group,dc=com,dc=xyz,dc=cz> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(objectClass=person))
# requesting: 1.1 
#

# XYZ, People, XY, xyz.com
dn: cn=XYZ,ou=People,o=XY,dc=group,dc=com,dc=xyz,dc=cz

...

# search result
search: 2
result: 4 Size limit exceeded

# numResponses: 4
# numEntries: 3
```

But when I use the filter:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p 393 -x -z 3 -b "o=XY,dc=group,dc=com,dc=xyz,dc=cz" "(&(objectClass=person)(memberOf=cn=X,ou=BusinessRoles,ou=AccessControl,o=XYZ,dc=group,dc=com,dc=xyz,dc=cz))"
```

I get no results.

Did I make any mistake in the query? Is the `memberOf` syntax OK?

Comment: Do you get any memberOf values with your first search?

Comment: @BertoldKolics - thanks for reply. When I look at user 'xyz' witch is one of members of group X in result set, there is no 'memberOf' field.

Comment: I should have asked you to replace `1.1` from the end of your first search query with `memberOf`. If you still do not get a `memberOf` value, then you are likely using a built-in group.

Comment: Hi, there is no `memberOf` value in results, even if I replace the `1.1` with `memberOf` in search query.

Comment: The thing is, I am not aware of the way the grouping is done, I do just read the data from AD (the users are assigned to groups in another application).

Comment: I do not see any authentication in the above examples (no bind DN provided using the `-D` argument and no password sent using the `-w` argument). This could be another reason why you do not see the value.

Comment: I think it really boils down to how this app you have in the screenshot query the data. @BertoldKolics already pointed out some possibilities. I'd like to add one - port 393 you have in your example does not look familiar, can you do ldapsearch for user account but against 3268 or 3269? In case these are referrals your application is able to chase made you will be able to read memberOf value for that user from global catalog.

Comment: @MartinLhotsky - I have tried the two ports you have mentioned. Nothing listens on this ports. The port 393 was provided to me by customer's AD administrator.

Comment: @BertoldKolics - I have no other than anonymous read access to this AD, could this be a problem?

Comment: It is very likely. I am even surprised that your first example returns anything. I am not sure why any administrator would open up Active Directory like that.

Comment: @BertoldKolics - well, I just discovered it's not an AD. It's openLDAP. Could this be the couse of `memberOf` problem?

Comment: @shimon001 Was it really so much trouble to *fix your question*?

Comment: @EJP - I haven't mentioned AD in my question, just in comments. It seemed to me, that it would just add more mess in comments section, if I would have corrected my comments. However, I have now added the information about OpenLDAP to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Check with your admin to make sure that `memberOf` is [enabled](http://blog.adimian.com/2014/10/how-to-enable-memberof-using-openldap/) on the OpenLDAP server
- Check with your admin that anonymous access is allowed to this attribute

Comment: Note that if it isn't already enabled, enabling the `memberOf` overlay won't affect existing entries. The `memberOf` attribute will only be maintained by changes that are made to the DIT from then on.

Comment: @EJP I just want to thank you for writing this comment. I had a group were only half of the entries were made after enabling memberOf... so only these where displayed when using the filter. It was driving me nuts!